# What is the difference between .code/.data and code/data segment?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, microprocessors, emu8086

I was given a particular program code by my instructor, to sort a set of data using bubble sort in assembly language (8086 micro-processor instructions).
For all previous codes I had used the syntax:

```
DATA SEGMENT
    <DATA HERE>
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE
    START:
        <CODE HERE>
    CODE ENDS
END START
```

The code given by my instructor is below:

```
org 100h 
.data

array  db 9,6,5,4,3,2,1
count  dw 7

.code

mov cx,count      
dec cx   

nextscan:          
mov bx,cx
mov si,0 

nextcomp:

mov al,array[si]
mov dl,array[si+1]
cmp al,dl

jnc noswap 

mov array[si],dl
mov array[si+1],al

noswap: 

inc si
dec bx

jnz nextcomp

loop nextscan

mov cx,7
mov si,0

print:

mov al,array[si]  
add al,30h
mov ah,0eh
int  10h 
mov ah,2
mov dl , ' '
int 21h
inc si
loop print    

ret
```

I did not understand why the `data segment` and `code segment` were replaced by `.data` and `.code` respectively and that there is (apparently) no need to end those segments. Also, the `assume` directive is absent and the program still works fine.
What really confused me was that when I modified the program as below (changed syntax to what I was familiar with), the program did not work:

```
data segment

array  db 9,6,5,4,3,2,1
count  dw 7

data ends

code segment

assume ds:data, cs:code

start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov cx,count      
dec cx   

nextscan:          
mov bx,cx
mov si,0 

nextcomp:

mov al,array[si]
mov dl,array[si+1]
cmp al,dl

jnc noswap 

mov array[si],dl
mov array[si+1],al

noswap: 

inc si
dec bx

jnz nextcomp

loop nextscan

mov cx,7
mov si,0

print:

mov al,array[si]  
add al,30h
mov ah,0eh
int  10h 
mov ah,2
mov dl , ' '
int 21h
inc si
loop print    

ret 

code ends
end start
```

The above code resulted in an infinite loop while running. I use emu8086, if it helps. I need help in understanding the difference between `.data`/`.code` and `data segment`/`code segment` directives and when to use which one.

Comment: `.org 0100h` looks like a .com to me. add a "jmp start" after the .org, and a label "start:" before your first command (right after .code). btw : '.com' uses a simplified 64k setup, and is assuming that CS = DS

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to assembly, hence I did not understand by what do you mean by ".org 0100h looks like a .com." Also, what does a simplified 64k setup mean?

Comment: When you hit infinite loop with emu8086, you are very lucky, because it's not a real PC (back in 199x we had to push the reset button, wait till the OS did boot up, load all the stuff back, and hope we didn't forget to save last version to disk/floppy). Meanwhile in emu8086 just restart the simulation and go step by step in debugger per single instruction. Probably the setup of segment registers went wrong, but from your source it's not clear to me why, your version looks actually more solid than the lectors, so I would appreciate if you would check it out in debugger, where is `array` in mem.

Comment: Some notes - about (emu8086) assembler: the `segment`, `.code` and similar are not instructions, but assembler directives, so check always the documentation of your assembler. That said, I never found any decent emu8086 docs online (what [I found](http://w3.gazi.edu.tr/~akcayol/files/emu8086.pdf) did always look partial and not accurate enough for my taste), so I prefer to not touch/use it. You can get to some length by using old tasm/masm docs, as emu8086 is partially emulating them (BTW it completely ignores the `ASSUME` directive, which I would actually count as positive thing).

Comment: Some notes - about COM: com is binary format just loading the whole file (code+data bytes indifferent) from 0x0100 offset, setting `cs/ds/es/ss` to that particular segment, `sp` pointing to end of it (usually `0xFFFE`, but can differ slightly per DOS vendor), and starts it at 0x0100, so if you put data first into COM, they will be executed instead of code, probably crashing the whole thing. On contrary EXE has header with separate sections like code, data and stack - have three different segments set up and allocated by DOS (but they may overlap! If you write beyond in one, damaging other).

Comment: That's why `org 100h` implies COM target, because with .EXE you don't need to put first instruction at cs:0100h, .EXE has separate code segment and can start at whichever entry point you specify. By using `org 100h` directive you adjust virtual address of following instruction during compilation, so the next labels and jumps will use the proper offsets in the COM file. But the instructors code is goulash, using `org 100h` ahead of `.data`, which makes no sense, if it's EXE, the `org` is useless, if it's COM, it will execute the `array` bytes, so it must be EXE with useless `org` directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ped7g, much needed and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using the directive `org 100h` then you need to end your program manually, so replace `ret` like this :

```
int 21h
inc si
loop print    

;ret 
mov ax, 4c00h      ;◄■■ END PROGRAM PROPERLY AND
int 21h            ;◄■■ RETURN CONTROL TO OS.

code ends
end start
```

The directive `org 100h` organizes de program in a way it fits in only one segment and the behavior is different. If you don't use this directive then your program is a "standard" executable (DOS) separated in segments.

Actually, you should always end your assembly programs manually to ensure everything is ok, with or without `org 100h`.

Oh, yes, about your question, there is no significant difference between ".data/.code and data segment/code segment directives", the only difference that comes to my mind is that you have to close segments when you are using `code segment` while `.code` does not require it. The infinite loop was not caused for replacing `.code` by `code segment`, the problem was returning control to OS properly. So you can use `.code` or `code segment` as you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped and now I understand assembly in much more detail. I am able to clear all my doubts on basis of your answer.